# How to turn Reingold–Tilford Tree into double sided tree in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, visualization, data-visualization

I am presently working on this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184 and am seeking advice on how to convert this tree into a double sided tree. The reason behind me using this tree structure is my texts/labels are very long and want to fit them in one single page. I also tried the option of radial tree but the long labels create overlaps with other labels. I tried to wrap some text according to a parameter called size but wasn't successful. My code for radial tree is available in this link http://jsfiddle.net/hv6wc7x5/ The actual labels which I want to use are very long as shown in the link. I cannot discuss the labels as this is a part of research work and cannot be shown publicly.

Basically I wan't to ask two questions in this post. First, is there a way to transform the normal Reingold–Tilford tree into a double sided tree.

And the second question is if there is a way to wrap the text for selected texts according to the size attribute given in the JSON. The code I want to change is given below but it doesn't work, if any one can help me in fixing this it would be great. In the last line of the code segment, I want to call the wrap function(an internal method in my code) based on the check that my attribute size equals to some value but I am unable to do it. Can anyone let me know how can I improve the last line?

```
node.append("text")
                  .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? 10 : -10; })
                  .attr("dy", ".31em")
                  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                  .attr("wraper", function(d) { return d.size == "3534" ? node.call(wrap,0) : node.call(wrap,0);
});
```

It would be great if anyone of the above questions are answered although I would love that my first question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by double sided tree ? You mean two trees side by side ? If so you'll have to split your data.

As for the second question, can't you use nodes.filter. filter them via your 'size' attribute in your data ?

Comment: By double tree I mean is that the root node is in the middle and the branches branch both to the left and right. (I-I) like this.

Comment: that's just how your data is set out. If you want to split it yourself you'll have to split the data

Comment: Can you show me a small example? If I split the data how will the tree branch both in left and right directions?

Comment: the way you want it : 'he root node is in the middle and the branches branch both to the left and right', is purely how your data is set out. Whats the reason for wanting it to branch both left and right ?

Comment: I want the length of the tree to get reduced and width to increase so that I can print it in one paper in landscape mode.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hv6wc7x5/2/: Line 416 on here is where you give the nodes their positions. Change the x/y value to change where the nodes are drawn. And line 402 is where you change the size of the radial tree. Use this info in a normal tree layout to change the size of the tree. If you want to shorten the length, you'll have to make the vertical gap ('y') smaller, and if you want the width bigger then make the horizontal gap ('x') bigger. If you put together a normal tree with your data then Ill mess about with it and sort it for you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answer, the best course of action is to split the data into a "left" and "right" tree. Each of these trees has a common node, the "root node".

When rendering the tree "all" you have to do is keep the root nodes on top of each other.